# multiple prototype cell header moves when deleting

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, tableheader

I have two prototype cells. One for displaying data & other I am using for header view.

When I try to delete my regular cell. The header cell moves with it.

[image]

I don't want header to move when I try to delete regular cells.

I have disable user interactions on header prototype cell. Still it keeps moving. In commit editing style I do immediate return for header prototype cell. Still it keeps moving. I don't know what else to do. Please help.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if tableView == upcomingTableView {

        if let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") {

            headerCell.textLabel?.text = sectionNames[section]

            headerCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Rs\(sum[section])"

            headerCell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

            headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

            return headerCell
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

cell for row at index path is also very regular code.

Comment: Add some code from your table view delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Create an UIView and add tableViewCell as subview and return the UIView.

**Solution in Swift:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") {

        //Create an UIView programmatically
        let headerView = UIView()

        headerCell.textLabel?.text = (section == 0) ? "Apple" : "Microsoft"
        headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        //Add cell as subview to UIView
        headerView.addSubview(headerCell)

        //Return the header view
        return headerView
    }

    return nil

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying but content view make blank cell. I also created fresh new project & tried with fake data. Content view renders blank white space.

Comment: @ApoorvMote: The reason behind header View is moving along with other cell is because it is inheriting the characteristics of UITableViewCell i.e., Sliding left while editing. Yes returning cell.contentView is not working is because of this I guess. I'll update my answer with Sample Swift Code.

Comment: It fixes the delete issue but it creates another issue for me. Header view bleeds into table cell. I can fix this by hard coding header view height to 44.0 CGFloat. But I don't like hard coding value. How Do I stop header view from bleeding into table cell?

Comment: Yes it will because it's taking the default cell height defined for the table view. You have to use height for row at index path to handle the height, since it's a table view cell. Another approach would be if you custom table view cell for header view cell either as separate xib or prototype cells in storyboard you have customize your height from size inspector.

Comment: Yeah I am able to display it properly but again the problem is I am hard coding value either programatically with height for row at index path or prototype cell height from size inspector. My guess is the default height automatically increases for bigger screen like iPad. If I hardcode values then it will look smaller on iPad.

Comment: The default cell height is 44 irrespective of device size. If you want it to be dynamic you have to use Auto layout with Custom Table View Cell as Xib. Even if you are using Auto layout you have to define height constraint at some point so it's part of your design. If you want different height for different device models you have to make use of size classes in Auto layout.